# joomla 3 error: 0 Cannot open file for writing log

Tags: php, permissions, migration, joomla3.0

I'm migrating my joomla 3.3.6 project from local to online server, but I get this error when I try to login into my administrator panel:

> Error: 0 Cannot open file for writing log

My tmp and logs paths are correct in my configuration.php, and the permissions of the folders and files are correct too (755 and 644).

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Try to temporarily increase permissions for these folders up to 0777

Comment: I did it umka but it doesn't works, any other idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you done the migration, the configure paremeters were changing also. Access the root folder where you installed Joomla, there you will locate a file with name "configuration.php". Open the file and change the following lines with the new path of logs and tmp folders:

```
public $log_path = '/path/to/the/joomla/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/path/to/the/jooomla/tmp';
```

Also please check the permissions of the above folders when modifying.
In CentOS I changed the permissions of logs/error.php to 666 then it works.

Comment: Pls pay attention it works on the earlier version of Joomla.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Check path of your application, by

```
<?php
   $path = getcwd();
   echo "Your Absolute Path is:" . $path;
?>
```

then set

```
$log_path = 'Your Absolute Path'/logs
```

If it does not solve issue, then

First check in ssh who owns the `/var/www` directory by:

```
ls -la /var
```

Then check what user apache uses

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

or you can use:

```
ps aux | grep http
```

output:

```
apache   29672  0.0  1.3 388232 14240
root     29679  0.0  0.2 110456  2252
```

in my case apache user for `/var/www` was `apache`

so after this I made `apache` the owner of `/var/www` by:

```
sudo chown -R apache /var/www
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to resolve.
Access configuration.php using FTP or cpanel.
Edit directly in cpanel or download it to your computer using ftp.
Edit the Log and Tmp paths to .../log and .../tmp respectly.
That solves it.
Get back on Joomla backend to verify by Accessing System>>System Information>>Directory Permissions.
Hope that helps.